# At in my career VS at my career

Tags: prepositions, american-english, british-english

Is this sentence correct?

> Wherever I am at **in** my career I do big films.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: At any position in my career, I do big films.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"in" is necessary here. A career is not a physical place, so we cannot be "at" it; we can only be "in" it, as part of it. It's the same as "in my family":

> "at" suggests that you are physically located; "in" suggests that you
>   belong.

Of course, "in" can also mean "inside" a physical place - in the store, in the cup, etc.

Some objects can take "in" or "at". For example, we can say "at the store" (ie, not necessarily inside it), but we can't say "at the cup" (we would say "near the cup").

We can also say "In my job" (as part of it) or "at my job" (at the place where I work), but we can't say "at my career".

> So the sentence you have is like this: "Wherever I am (at) / in my
>   career" not "Wherever I am / at (in) my career".

**Extra: it is "at" that is actually the optional preposition:**

"at" here is like a substitute for "up to", which indicates a point that you have reached in a progression.

For example,

> "I am up to level 3"
>
> "I am up to $50,000/year"

But for some things, we would be more likely to use "at":

> "I am at a point in my career where I am learning many new things"

This situation is not necessarily about progression. As a beginner, you might be learning many new things, but when you move to a senior level, or simply take on new tasks, you might again be learning many new things. You can be "at" this point more than once, whereas you can (or should!) only be "up to" a point once.

The "at" is not completely necessary in your sentence - "Wherever I am in my career" can also mean "at whatever point".

But, "at" does help to distinguish from a question of physical location.

> For example, if I am reading a large book, someone might say "Where
>   are you up to in the book?" or "Where are you at in the book?" to
>   distinguish from "Where are you in the book?" - which could mean that
>   there is a picture of me in the book and they want to know on which
>   page it appears.

Note: In this example, "up to" is exactly appropriate - I have reached a certain point of the book - so using "at" here is more informal.

"at" is also often used to get an exact location rather than a general one.

> For example, I am at the beach. If you call me and ask "Where are
>   you?" I would reply "At the beach". If you already know I'm at the
>   beach and you want to meet me, you might ask "Where are you at?" to
>   find out exactly where I am on the beach.

Here, "up to" is not appropriate because you are not asking about a stage of progression; however, "at" is again informal ("Whereabouts are you?" is more standard).

**In short, the preposition we need here is "in". "at" is not necessary, but can be used to distinguish from physical location or to be more specific. Sometimes, "at" in this way is informal.**

Answer (score 1):

No. "At" is a preposition, and a preposition requires an object. But there is no object for "at" here.

You can simply say, "Wherever I am in my career ..."

Americans frequently talk "at" on to sentences about a location -- "Where are you at?" and the like -- when it is unnecessary and incorrect. The simple rule is, Don't say "at" unless it has an object.

"Where are you at?" Wrong: no object. Should be simply, "Where are you?"

"Are you at the store?" Right. The object of "at" is "the store". Without the "at", the question would become, "Are you the store?", which is asking if the one addressed is a building, which seems very unlikely.

Comment: Like you, I answered the question focusing entirely on "at" - then I noticed that the OP had emboldened "in": they are actually asking why it is not "at my career"....

Comment: @Jay: I don't entirely agree. For a well-reasoned essay with a dissenting opinion, see [this](http://motivatedgrammar.wordpress.com/2008/08/06/where-are-you-at/).

Comment: @BobRodes Let's fight to the death over it! I find that article unconvincing. Yes, the rule against ending a sentence with a preposition is silly and pointless and has nothing to do with why I say "where you at?" is wrong. I agree with the "unnecessary" argument. Yes, there are words that are "unnecessary" but that add clarity to the sentence. But how does "at" add clarity to the sentence? The example given in the article you cite is a non sequitur. Why couldn't someone reply to "Where are you at?" by saying "In my car"? How does the "at" change the context from "on the bus" versus ...

Comment: ... "in my car" to "Route 42" versus "Elm Street"? And he fails to mention what seems to me the key point: that it is not only unnecessary but incomplete, because the preposition has no object. If he said, "At what highway exit are you?", then the "at" would have a preposition, "what exit". I wouldn't object to putting the preposition at the end: "What highway exit are you at?" At still has an object and serves a purpose in the sentence. But "Where you at?" just doesn't make sense.